# Jenkins doesnt dispay welcome page (UBUNTU 18.04)

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, cd

Jenkins is not diplaying welcome page to get started, instead it displays end points like below. http://localhost:8080 or http://127.0.0.1:8080

```
{
  "paths": [
    "/api",
    "/api/v1",
    "/apis",
    "/apis/",
    "/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io",
    "/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io",
    "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/apps",
    "/apis/apps/v1",
    "/apis/apps/v1beta1",
    "/apis/apps/v1beta2",
    "/apis/authentication.k8s.io",
    "/apis/authentication.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/authorization.k8s.io",
    "/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/autoscaling",
    "/apis/autoscaling/v1",
    "/apis/autoscaling/v2beta1",
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like `8080` port is being consumed by other application. To make sure do following

**Try this**

Stop the Jenkins

run the following command and if you see `connected` in output. means other process is using port.

```
➜  ~ telnet localhost 8080
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Try `8081` or other ports in command `telnet localhost 8081` and if you get  `Connection refused` then change your Jenkins Port to this one.

```
➜  ~ telnet localhost 8082
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```